# Why does same program requires yum update on one machine but not another?

Tags: fedora, yum, upgrade

I have `cpio-2.11-25.fc20.x86_64` installed on two machines:

This program does not require an update on the first machine, but I was presented with a higher version `2.11-28.fc20` on the second machine. To be certain that it is not a timing issue, I did `yum update` again on the first machine, and was presented with:

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No packages marked for update
```

Why does same program requires an update on one machine but not another?

Comment: Which distro version are you running on each machine?

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum: Apparently Fedora 20.

Comment: Compare the yum `/etc/yum.conf` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/` settings and repos for each machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings in `/etc/yum.conf` and under the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. Check the main config of `/etc/yum.conf` since these settings take priority over others.

> The values you define in the [main] section of the /etc/yum.conf file
>   may override values set in individual [repository] sections.

Compare the one that updates to the one that doesn't. You likely have different settings or you are missing a repository on the machine that doesn't update.

[System Administrator's Guide Yum 4.3. Configuring Yum and Yum Repositories](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the systems are identical, run `yum clean all` which clears yum cache of packages , metadata and headers.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some odd activity like this when distributing identical VMs on EC2.
I always assume something awful has happened and rebuild all of the nodes involved.

I would suggest a `yum clean all`, also comparing the Linux kernel version, any associated yum repo configs and run reboots on both machines. If it's still behaving the same way, try removing the package from both machines, re-installing it and checking once again. If all else fails, rebuild the node.